# Package for pre-compiled boost libraries (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu

I'm trying to find the right boost package that comes pre-compiled as well. (For Ubuntu Lucid 10.04)

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev-all
```

I'm aware that most of boost is header only, but it looks like I don't have any lib files? I only got the files in /usr/include/boost/

Which package gives me the library files as well? (such as /usr/lib/boost/ or /usr/include/boost/lib/) ? Or are they already installed and I just can't find them? I would prefer to not have to compile it myself from source..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in /usr/lib for files beginning with 'libboost'.

Answer (score 2):

`libboost-dev` packages include both the libraries and the headers necessary to develop using boost. It is also split into different packages. For instance `libboost-thread-dev` for the `boost.thread` library: It depends on `libboost-thread1.42-dev` (on my system), and:

```
$ dpkg -L libboost-thread1.42-dev 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libboost-thread1.42-dev
...
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.a
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a
```

There you have the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo aptitude install libboost-all-dev`